# not able to change class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code to calculate some qty in the table which loaded dynamically. And also i have added code to change the class of a  if the qty is less than zero. But in my case, that changing the color at one time i.e., in first row not in rest of the rows.

```js
$(document).ready(function()  {   
    $("#itemtable").on("change", "input", function() {
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var received = parseFloat(row.find("td:eq(5)").text()); // get received qty
      var accepted = parseFloat($(row).find("td:eq(6) input[type='text']").val()); 
      if (received < accepted){
       alert("Accepted qty greater than received qty, Please check!");
      } else {
       var rejected = received - accepted;
       row.find("td:eq(7) input[type='text']").val(isNaN(rejected) ? "" : rejected); 
      }
      if (rejected > 0){
       alert("change class");
       $('#rejec').removeClass('tb1').addClass('tb2'); 
      }      
   });
});
```

Comment: Can we see the html so we can reproduce

Comment: Are you sure the problem is that the class is not applied, or instead that the rule is not specific enough to override others? You can check this in the DOM inspector

Comment: even i could see that flow entering into rejected > 0 (as true) but not applied

Comment: Try with different, temporary, unique classes (to remove potential specificity issue).  Ensure `#rejec` has content (so div is not invisible). Provide a working example (that shows it not working...), see  [mcve]. Separately: fix logic flow as `rejected>0` should be inside the above `else`.

Comment: Sorry, missed this bit *"in first row not in rest of the rows"* - your `$("#reject")` needs to include the row, ie `$("#rejec", row)`.  In general, **IDs should be unique** - if #rejec is **on each row**, it will only change the first one (as you've found).  Use classes and filter to the row `$("#rejec", row)` or (using your other code) `row.find("#rejec")`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes thanks a lot! its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in first row not in rest of the rows

The selector to find the reject text `$("#reject")` needs to include the row, ie:

```
$("#rejec", row).removeClass('tb1').addClass('tb2');
```

or

```
row.find("#rejec").removeClass('tb1').addClass('tb2');
```

In general, IDs should be unique - if `#rejec` is on each row, it will only change the first one (as you've found). Ideally, use classes and filter to the event's row.

Answer (score 0):

as above mentioned , changed this piece of code to get the required result

```js
if (rejected > 0){
       row.find("td:eq(7) input[type='text']").removeClass('tb1').addClass('tb2');  
      }
```